# How to give percentage to UITableViewCell height base on the height of UITableView? Then All UITableViewCell can show out without scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

[image]
In Autolayout, how to give percentage to UITableViewCell height base on the height of UITableView? Then  All UITableViewCell can show out in  One View without scroll.

Comment: if u want to do this...why not just make a view with 5 child view inside? if not, you can try use stackview , it might work, if it not, u can use code inside the `heightForRow` delegate method, just get the screen frame then split to 5

Comment: Thx for reply! The reason why i need to use UITableView, because some uitableviewcell migh remove base on some setting, then other item can auto scroll to top

Comment: thx for let me know UIStackView, i think it is good but just for ios9, and may be i try use OAStackView to support ios8 (becase i need to support ios9) https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView

Comment: i think its best to use some few lines of code to achieve this, in your case it seems easier to achieve what u want

Answer (score 1):

First make a property for numberOfRows to be returned in tableView. Let's say rowCount is the property name. Then

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.frame.size.height / rowCount
}
```

Comment: It's far more efficient to set the table view's rowHeight property than it is to implement this delegate method. Only use this delegate method if some rows have different heights.

Comment: But what if you want either of the 4 or 5 or 6 rows for different cases? Editing the rowHeight property in all cases won't be suitable

Comment: The question seems to be asking how to make all of the rows fit to fill the table view without scrolling. This implies that all of the rows are the same height. In that case, setting `rowHeight` is more efficient than implementing the `heightForRow` delegate method.

Comment: I want to solve this problem by using storyboard only, because MVC

Comment: @nullmicgo Adding code doesn't violate MVC. I hope you don't think you can write an entire (useful) app with no code.

Comment: yes yes, sure, i just want to try put as much as  ui stuff inside storyboard, then other people can understand my UI by storyboard